# How to upload files from multiple fields of same mongodb collection using multer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, multer

I want to upload images from several fields of the same collection. I am able to upload using one field.

route : service.js

```
router.post('/register', upload.array('daycare.DCImage',10),(req, res) => {
  var paths = req.files.map(file => file.path)
  const newService = new Services(req.body);
  newService.daycare.DCImage = paths
    newService
        .save(newService)
        .then(data => {
            res.send(data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
              message:
                err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Service."
            });
        });
})
```

Like **daycare.DCImage** i want to make **grooming.groomingImage**, **trainer.TrainingImage**, **dogwalker.DWImage**, **breeding.breedingImages** fields also to facilitate image uploading.

This code currently works perfectly, How can I alter the code to get the desired functions?

I tried including extra upload.array() like

```
router.post('/register', upload.array('daycare.DCImage',10), upload.array('grooming.GroomingImage',10 ), upload.array('dogwalker.DWImage', 10) , upload.array('trainer.TrainingImage', 10 ), upload.array('breeding.breedingImage', 10) ,(req, res) )
```

and also other fields in the same upload.array()

```
router.post('/register', upload.array('daycare.DCImage', 'grooming.GroomingImage', 'trainer.TrainingImage' , 'breeding.breedingImage', 10),(req, res) )
```

But it did not work.

This is the model service.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const User = require('./User');
const ServiceSchema = new Schema({    
    daycare : {
        description : {type : String},
        DCImage : [{type : String}],
        additionalServices : {type : String},
    },
    grooming : {
        description : {type : String},
        GroomingImage : [{type : String}],
        additionalServices : {type : String},
    },
    dogwalker : {
        description : {type : String},
        DWImage : [{type : String}],
        additionalServices : {type : String},
    },
    trainer : {
       
        description : {type : String},
        TrainingImage : [{type : String}],
        price : {
            daily : {type : String},
            weekly : {type : String},
            monthly : {type : String}
        },
        additionalServices : {type : String},
    },
    breeding : {
        breed : {type : String},
        age : {type : String},      
        breedingImages:[{type:String}],        
    },
});
module.exports = Services = mongoose.model('Services', ServiceSchema);
```

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36096893/5433067

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multer upload.**fields** like this,

```
router.post('/register', upload.fields([
    { name: "field_name", maxCount: 1 },
    { name: "field_name", maxCount: 1 },
    { name: "field_name", maxCount: 1 },
    { name: "field_name", maxCount: 1 }
  ])
  ,(req, res) );
```

and then upload function like this,

```
const upload = multer({
  storage: 'path-to-storage',
  limits: { fileSize: 100000 },
  key: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
});
```