# How to send multiple files with different name attributes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, file, multer

I have a form with 2 input field with type file and with different name attr.
I wanna send these files and store it on my db, on the backedn i am using multer.

Now here is my form

```
<form aciton="/uploadFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
     <input type="file" name="file1" required multiple />
     <input type="file" name="file2" required multiple />
     <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

On the backend this is my what i am doing

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({

  destination:(req,file,cb)=>{
    cb(null,'./public/uploads');
  },

  filename:(req,file,cb)=>{
    cb(null,file.originalname+'-'+Date.now())
  }
```

})

[image]

The Problem is that if i name both input field same, then its working, otherwise its not working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096805/uploading-multiple-files-with-multer-but-from-different-fields

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uploading multiple files with multer, but from different fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096805/uploading-multiple-files-with-multer-but-from-different-fields)